# access jquery slider value in flask

Tags: jquery, flask

I want to access the values of variables minexp and maxexp of jquery slider in flask.

```
//HTML CODE
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
     range: true,
     min: 0,
     max: 15,
    values: [ 0, 15 ],
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $("#amount").val( "" + ui.values[ 0 ] + "-" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
    $('.abcd').html('Experience - Min - '+ ui.values[0] + ' Max -' 
    +ui.values[1]);
   }
   });
   $("#amount" ).val( "" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
  "-" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
   } );
</script>


<form action="/process" method="post" data-parsley-validate="" id="Data">
   <div class="form-left-w3l">
    <p class="expRange_para">
    <label for="amount" class="abcd">Experience</label>
    <input type="text" id="amount" min="0" max="100" readonly 
    style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;" name="expRange">
    </p>
    <div id="slider-range"></div>
    </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#jobFormData").on('submit',function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
                    var amount = $("#amount").val();
                    var exp = amount.split('-');
                    var minexp = exp[0];
                    var maxexp = exp[1];

    $.ajax({
            method: 'post',
            url: '/process,
              type:'POST',
               traditional:true,
                    data:{
                        minexp:minexp,
                        maxexp:maxexp,
                            }
       })
  }
```

In FLASK tried by passing the variables minexp and maxexp but got a NULL value. And instead of minexp and maxexp if I write expRange(i.e input attribute name) I get 0.

```
//FLASK CODE
app.route('/process', methods=['POST'])
def process():
minexp1=request.form.get("minexp")
maxexp1=request.form.get("maxexp")
return minexp1
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the **minexp** and **maxexp** variable in your AJAX request as parameters:

```
       data:{
           minexp:minexp,
           maxexp:maxexp,
       }
```

So if you want to access them from your Fask code you need to use:
**request.args.get('minexp')** and **request.args.get('maxexp')**.

**request.form** retrieve values from you HTML Form element not your AJAX URL request, so if you still want to use **request.form.get('minexp')** and **request.form.get('maxexp')** you need to change your Form in order to have two inputs one with an id minexp and the other with an id maxexp.

I recommend using the **request.args.get** it make more since in this case!

**request.args:** to retrieve the URL parameters value.

**request.form:** to retrieve value from HTML elements.

**request.files:** to retrieve the file from the HTML elements.

Comment: I changed it to request.args.get but still it is not working.

Comment: don't forget to remove "action="/process" method="post"" from the Form tag and make sure the type of minexp and maxexp is srting, also  i have forgot the quotes in my response so it should be  request.args.get('maxexp') and request.args.get('minexp')

Comment: The code that i mentioned here is just  a part of actual one. I can't remove method="post" bcoz there are some more fields in form which needs that. I am able to get all the values by request.form.get  except the slider one. Can i use both the method post and get together in my HTML code??

Comment: in that case instead of the amount input make a max input and a min input separately then use for them **request.form.get**, you kind need to change your approach  otherwise you make **request.form.get("amount")** and separate the value of min and max with flask after retrieving the whole amount value. Hope this help you